# Add option repeating in Link to add to google calendar

Tags: calendar

I am unclear about the exact format to have a link on a website that will add a single event to a users google calendar.
Here's an example link:

https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Your+Event+Name&dates=20140127T224000Z/20140320T221500Z&details=For+details,+link+here:+http://www.example.com&location=Waldorf+Astoria,+301+Park+Ave+,+New+York,+NY+10022&sf=true&output=xml

key query parameters:

> `text dates details location...`

But but I do not know how to add repeat
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJrAr.png)

Answer (score 0):

add the following parameter
`&RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;`
see documentation here
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `recur` query parameter to the url ?
`&recur=RRULE:FREQ%3DDAILY;INTERVAL%3D2;COUNT%3D7`